# How can I send grid item to next row if there isn't enough space swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm somewhat new to swift and am struggling with this seemingly simple problem. I want three columns in my grid UNLESS the content of the grid item doesn't fit within the set width of the column. Specifically, I have filter buttons and some of which have long names. I want to send the TagView of "Breakfast" to the next line and move each one along so that they all fit and the text doesn't have to wrap. Not sure how to do this though.

I've tried adjusting the minimum and maximum values within the grid items and adjusted how many GridItems are in the columns. However, this hasn't worked unfortunately. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    var filterBar: some View {
        VStack {
            filterBarTitle
            if filtersOpened {
                let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 85), spacing:0)]
                
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(allRecipeTags) { recipeTag in
                        TagView(tag: recipeTag, selected: selectedTags.contains(recipeTag), canToggle: true, onTap: {
                            if selectedTags.contains(recipeTag) {
                                print("removing \(recipeTag)")
                                selectedTags.removeAll(where: { $0 == recipeTag })
                            } else {
                                print("adding \(recipeTag)")
                                selectedTags.append(recipeTag)
                            }
                        })
                        .border(.red)
                    }
                }
                .border(.blue)
            }
        }
        .padding([.top, .bottom])
        .border(width: 1, edges: [.bottom], color: Color("24292F").opacity(0.3))
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding([.bottom], filtersOpened ? 8 : 0)
    }
```

[FilterBar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvhGW.png)

Comment: All of the rows in a `LazyVGrid` need to have the same number of columns, which may be preventing your view from wrapping the way you'd like. Instead, consider taking advantage of Apple's new [Layout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layout) protocol to create your own wrapping view. There's an interesting [package on GitHub](https://github.com/FluidGroup/swiftui-WrapLayout/tree/main) that seems to do exactly what you're looking for with support for iOS 14+.

Comment: @MarcelQT Please have a look this [Github](https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-tags-swiftui/) , It might help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation of a custom `Layout`, which hopefully suits your purpose:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let tags = ["Appetizers","Baking","Breakfast","Dessert","Dinner","Fish","Lunch","Main","Quick","Side","Snack","Spicy","Vegan","Vegetarian"]
    
    var body: some View {

        FlowLayout {
                ForEach(tags, id: \.self) { tag in
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text(tag)
                            .fixedSize()
                            .font(.headline)

                        Circle()
                    }
                    .padding(10)
                            .background(
                                Capsule().stroke(.red)
                            )
                            .padding(5)
                }
        }
    }
}


struct FlowLayout: Layout {
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let sizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }

        var totalHeight: CGFloat = 0
        var totalWidth: CGFloat = 0

        var lineWidth: CGFloat = 0
        var lineHeight: CGFloat = 0

        for size in sizes {
            if lineWidth + size.width > proposal.width ?? 0 {
                totalHeight += lineHeight
                lineWidth = size.width
                lineHeight = size.height
            } else {
                lineWidth += size.width
                lineHeight = max(lineHeight, size.height)
            }

            totalWidth = max(totalWidth, lineWidth)
        }

        totalHeight += lineHeight

        return .init(width: totalWidth, height: totalHeight)
    }

    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        let sizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }

        var lineX = bounds.minX
        var lineY = bounds.minY
        var lineHeight: CGFloat = 0

        for index in subviews.indices {
            if lineX + sizes[index].width > (proposal.width ?? 0) {
                lineY += lineHeight
                lineHeight = 0
                lineX = bounds.minX
            }

            subviews[index].place(
                at: .init(
                    x: lineX + sizes[index].width / 2,
                    y: lineY + sizes[index].height / 2
                ),
                anchor: .center,
                proposal: ProposedViewSize(sizes[index])
            )

            lineHeight = max(lineHeight, sizes[index].height)
            lineX += sizes[index].width
        }
    }
}
```